# Second monitor not working in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, multiple-monitors

I know this question has been asked before, I followed every correct answer and still my secondary display is just black.

So, here's what I did recently:

- Booted in Safe Mode
- Used DDU (Display Driver Uninstaller) to fully uninstall old Intel HD Graphics Driver
- Booted into user mode again, installed manufacturer's driver (link: http://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp72001-72500/sp72380.exe)
- Rebooted and second monitor still not working.

I have tried all combinations with (Windows button + P): extended monitor, duplicate, and even 2nd monitor only in a desperate attempt.

Also, by going into Intel's "Graphic options" from right-clicking, I configured double screens to be extended, and set the second's to the lowest resolution, but still to no avail.

Here's some specs:

PC: HP Probook 4540s (the i5 version, Intel HD 4000 Graphics)

Graphic Driver version: 9.17.10.4229

I hope to hear from you soon, thanks to anyone who's going to try and help me!

EDIT: Forgot to mention that I even tried the latest driver published by Intel for W10 x64 on their website, and still had the same result!

EDIT2: Monitor model is Asus VW221D and I'm connecting via VGA cable. The monitor worked under Windows 7 on another Probook 4540s.

Comment: What is the model of your monitor?  Are you connecting via HDMI or VGA?

Comment: Whoops, sorry.

Model is Asus VW221D, connecting via VGA.
I have also tried another monitor (an LG), still gave the same problem

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation, I discovered that the VGA Output port wasn't working, as attaching an HDMI cable would result in 2nd monitor displaying correctly.

At the moment, I am using a VGA monitor and using a VGA 2 HDMI adapter to attach it to the HDMI output port of my laptop.